# Validate if the string is already compressed

Tags: c#, string, compression

i am receiving compressed string data from server side application, then i am decompressing the string, how can i validate if the data i am receiving is compressed or not.

```
string compressedData = Getting from some function;

//What can i add here to check if the compressedData string contain already compressed string or not.

    string decompressedData = Decompress(compressedData);


    //Decompress Function
        static string Decompress(string compressedText)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(compressedText))
                    return "";

                byte[] gzBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedText);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0);
                    ms.Write(gzBuffer, 4, gzBuffer.Length - 4);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[msgLength];

                    ms.Position = 0;
                    using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }

                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try if decompression succeeds

```
string compressedData = "Getting from some function";
string decompressedData = null;

bool compressed = true; //your result
try
{
    decompressedData = Decompress(compressedData);
}
catch
{
    compressed = false;
}
```